# Tcpdf - writeHtml() issue

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf

I need create pdf file width 62mm  height 35mm with content:

[image]

I use tcpdf for it:

```
    $pdf = new TCPDF('L', PDF_UNIT, [62,35], true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetMargins(2, 2, 2);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(5);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(0);
    $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $html = '<style>p{font-size: 5px;border-bottom:1px solid #9A0000;}span{font-size: 16px;}</style><p>mandelaugen group gmbh, lzernerstrasse 49, 5712 beinwil am se</p><span>Company</span><br><span>First name Last name</span><br><span>Address</span><br><span>5712 Beinwil am Se</span>';
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
    $pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');
```

Cant undertstand why last line is on second page, it must be on first page. And how add littele top margin?

My result is like this:

[image]

Comment: What happens is make the font size slightly smaller (say 14 instead of 16)?

Comment: I will tel you why doesn't you use mpdf/mpdf library ?

Comment: I tried do this: `$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['format' => [62, 35]]);
$html = '<style>@page {
     margin: 0;
     margin-top:5px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     margin-left: 10px;
    }
    p{font-size: 6px;border-bottom: 1px solid darkred;padding-bottom: 2px;margin-bottom: 1px;}
    span{font-size: 18px;font-weight: bolder;}
    
    </style>';

$html.='<p>mandelaugen group gmbh, lzernerstrasse 49, 5712 beinwil am see</p><span>Company</span><br>
<span>First Name Last Name</span><br><span>Address</span><br><span>5712 Beinwil am Se</span>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();`

Comment: this is my result: https://clip2net.com/s/43u5wvd

Comment: how can i chnage it for become the same as on example?

Answer (score 1):

I see in the comments that you may have switched to mPdf, but I'll leave this here for future searchers:

Beyond just setting the margins, there is also an automatic page break that is on by default with it's own page break bottom margin. I think the default is 2 centimeters.

If you want to disable automatic page break entirely, call:

```
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);
```

Or, if you'd like to retain automatic page breaking, but want to set your own page-break margin, set the first parameter to true, and the second to your desired page-break margin in PDF units.

For example:

```
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 0); //Use entire page before auto break.
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 10); //In the above example, 10mm
```